# Are multiplications after division UNSAFE?

Tags: solidity, security, slither

I have a smart contract which essentially does this:

```
uint256 tokenRate =  _pair.a2  * PRECISION_FACTOR / _pair.a1;
uint256 toSend = _amount * tokenRate / PRECISION_FACTOR;
uint256 feeToOwner2 = toSend * fee / 10000;
```

I've used a static analysis tool such as [slither](https://github.com/crytic/slither) and it's throwing the error below saying "performs a multiplication on the result of a division".

Is it something to worry about? I thought maths is "safe" in Solidity, especially since the integration of `SafeMath` since solidity 0.8. (this contract uses a solidity version above 0.8)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slither [has documentation](https://github.com/crytic/slither/wiki/Detector-Documentation) for its detectors that explains the reasoning behind them. For this detector (["Divide before multiply"](https://github.com/crytic/slither/wiki/Detector-Documentation#divide-before-multiply)), the explanation is:

> Solidity's integer division truncates. Thus, performing division before multiplication can lead to precision loss.

And the example exploit scenario is:

> ```
> contract A {
>     function f(uint n) public {
>         coins = (oldSupply / n) * interest;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> If `n` is greater than `oldSupply`, `coins` will be zero. For example, with `oldSupply = 5; n = 10, interest = 2`, coins will be zero.
>
> If `(oldSupply * interest / n)` was used, `coins` would have been `1`.
>
> In general, it's usually a good idea to re-arrange arithmetic to perform multiplication before division, unless the limit of a smaller type makes this dangerous.

For your case, this issue can occur if `_pair.a1` or `_pair.a2` are greater than `PRECISION_FACTOR`.

For example:

```
// Assuming:
// _pair.a1 = 1000; _pair.a2 = 750; PRECISION_FACTOR = 10; _amount = 1; fee = 10

uint256 tokenRate = 750 * 10 / 1000; // 7.5 --> 7
uint256 toSend = 1 * 7 / 10; // 0.7 --> 0
uint256 feeToOwner2 = 0 * 10 / 10000; // 0
```

---

OpenZeppelin's `SafeMath` library was used to check for integer underflow and overflow; it did not affect division truncation issues like the above.